# Error: Can't find or load main class when using Java command after compiling a .Java file with multiple classes

Tags: java, cmd

I try to run the java command after compiling my .java file, the .java file contains multiple classes but only one public class and only one main method in the public class. It can't find the main class when all the .class files are in the same place. On netbeans it runs perfectly, on CMD is where the error appears. Also sorry if I make any mistakes in my writing, English isn't my main language, it is Spanish. Thats also why the classes and variables names are in Spanish.

I already checked that the class only have one main method, all the classes are on the same place and there is only one public class in the .java file

That is the code and as you can see only one public class and main is in public class.

```
    package dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b;
   public class Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Constructora constructora = new Constructora();
        ConstruyeCasas constructor_SencillaCasa = new ConstruyeCasasSencillas();
        ConstruyeCasas constructor_FamiliarCasa = new ConstruyeCasasFamiliares();

        constructora.setConstruyeCasas(constructor_SencillaCasa);
        constructora.construirCasa();

        Casa casa =  constructora.getCasa();
        System.out.println("Se ha construido una casa " + casa.getTipo());
        System.out.println("Con " + casa.getHabitaciones()+ " habitaciones");
        System.out.println("Con " + casa.getBanos()+ " baños");
        System.out.println("Con " + casa.getVentanas()+ " ventanas");
        System.out.println();
        constructora.setConstruyeCasas(constructor_FamiliarCasa);
        constructora.construirCasa();

        Casa casa2 =  constructora.getCasa();
        System.out.println("Se ha construido una casa " + casa2.getTipo());
        System.out.println("Con " + casa2.getHabitaciones()+ " habitaciones");
        System.out.println("Con " + casa2.getBanos()+ " baños");
        System.out.println("Con " + casa2.getVentanas()+ " ventanas");

    }


    }
```

//Clase producto

```
`class Casa{`

    private Integer habitaciones;
    private Integer banos;
    private Integer ventanas;
    private String tipo;

    public void setHabitaciones(Integer habitaciones){
        this.habitaciones = habitaciones;
    }    

    public void setBanos(Integer banos){
        this.banos = banos;
    }

    public void setVentanas(Integer ventanas){
        this.ventanas = ventanas;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo){
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Integer getHabitaciones(){
        return habitaciones;
    }

    public Integer getBanos(){
        return banos;
    }

    public Integer getVentanas(){
        return ventanas;
    }

    public String getTipo(){
        return tipo;
    }
}
```

//Clase Abstract Builder

```
abstract class ConstruyeCasas{
  protected Casa casa;`

    public Casa getCasa(){
        return casa;
    }

    public void crearNuevaCasa(){
        casa = new Casa();
    }

    public abstract void constuirHabitaciones();
    public abstract void construirBanos();
    public abstract void construirVentanas();
    public abstract void asignarTipo();
}
```

//Clase construye casas sencillas

```
  class ConstruyeCasasSencillas extends ConstruyeCasas{

        @Override
        public void constuirHabitaciones(){
            casa.setHabitaciones(1);
        }
        @Override
        public void construirBanos(){
            casa.setBanos(2);
        }
        @Override
        public void construirVentanas(){
            casa.setVentanas(5);
        }

        @Override
        public void asignarTipo(){
            casa.setTipo("Sencilla");
        }
    }

`//Clase construye casas familiares
`

    class ConstruyeCasasFamiliares extends ConstruyeCasas{
        @Override
        public void constuirHabitaciones(){
            casa.setHabitaciones(3);
        }
        @Override
        public void construirBanos(){
            casa.setBanos(4);
        }
        @Override
        public void construirVentanas(){
            casa.setVentanas(8);
        }

        @Override
        public void asignarTipo(){
            casa.setTipo("Familiar");
        }
    }
```

//Clase directora

```
   class Constructora{
        private ConstruyeCasas construyeCasas;

        public void setConstruyeCasas(ConstruyeCasas consCasas){
            construyeCasas = consCasas;
        }


        public Casa getCasa(){
            return construyeCasas.getCasa();
        }

        public void construirCasa(){
            construyeCasas.crearNuevaCasa();
            construyeCasas.constuirHabitaciones();
            construyeCasas.construirBanos();
            construyeCasas.construirVentanas();
            construyeCasas.asignarTipo();

        }
    }
```

The directory of the .java and the .class files are this:

```
C:\Users\hecto_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B\src\dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b
```

I expect that when I run java Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B in the CMD after running javac Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B.java will execute the program and doesn't give me the error: `Error Could not find or load the main class Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B.`

Comment: Can you show the actual java command that you type on the command line (do you include the full package name?), and also which directory you are in when running it.

Comment: Ok I'll type what command I write javac Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B.java and later java Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B in directory C:\Users\hecto_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B\src\dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b>

Comment: Try going to the src directory, and run “java dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b.Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B”     This is because the class is in a package (not the default package)

Comment: I'll try and tell you if that works

Comment: It works now. Thanks racraman, Do you know what I can do to make it run only with the Java java Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B command? Its because this is a homework and my teacher probably is only going to try to run the class name and not try to run with the folder containing the .java file

Comment: Just remove the package statement from the java file :)

Comment: So in the code I only need to remove the "package dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b;" line then, also how I give you like a good answer or something like that, you just saved my life with these homework. :)

Comment: Glad to help :)   I've just summarised as an answer that you can accept - Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is declared as :

```
package dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b;
public class Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B {
```

This means it is in the package `dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b`, and so :
- when run the whole package name must be supplied, and
- The current directory must be at the root (top-level) directory.

Putting these together means that to run the class, go to the src directory :

```
C:\Users\hecto_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B\src
```

And run the command:

```
java dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b.Dfutreras_ArqApp_AA19_2B
```

To run the class from the current directory, remove the line `package dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b` from the .java file(s), which will mean the class is in the "default" package.

Coincidentally, it is also worth mentioning that Java naming standards are that class names should be "CamelCase" (so without underscores)

Answer (score 0):

include (package dfutreras_arqapp_aa19_2b;) package in all your classes and then give it a try.